# How to run Hyper-V virtual machine headless?

Tags: virtualbox, hyper-v

I want to replace Hyper-V machine with VirtualBox. But I want some feature like VirtualBox's Headless start. How can I do this in Hyper-V VM?

Comment: Go to the settings of your VM, under Management, select Automatic Start Action and select the behavior you want:  Automatically start if it was running when the service stopped or Always start this virtual machine automatically.

Answer (score 0):

From a powershell prompt:

```
Start-VM $VMName -AsJob
```

The `-AsJob` is needed to keep it from opening VMConnect automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Start the VM normally, then close all the GUI windows. The VM runs on the background in a headless way .